# Bernie's Breakfast

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> **Moderator Note:** This is a current contest question on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/).

Bernie's Breakfast Buffet offers omelettes as part of their buffet on Saturday and Sunday. They offer 6 different toppings that you can have on your omelette. For each topping, you can either not have that topping, have a single serving, or have a double serving. How many different choices of omelettes are offered?

Comment: You stop in front of each topping, and say $0$ or $1$ or $2$.

Comment: is the answer to the problem $3^6$

Comment: Yes, $3^6$ is the right answer. You may be expected to multiply it out.

Comment: I feel like eating at Bernie's.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: Wouldn't suggest it. They probably use powdered eggs.

Comment: This is a [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/weekend-omelettes-at-bernies/?group=NKp1aUV3OfuM), as is the other question posed by the OP. Please close it for a week - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this is a [math problem on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/weekend-omelettes-at-bernies/?group=NKp1aUV3OfuM), and solutions are available. It got posted here as OP merely wants the numerical answer.

The top voted solution is:

[image]